# Create a list of default objects of a class in Python?

Tags: python

I have define a class in Python

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, children = []):
        self.children = children
```

I would like to create a list or array of default objects of class `node`. For example, something like in C++

```
node * nodes = node[100];
```

then `nodes` will point to an array of 100 default objects of class `node`.

How is it done similarly in Python? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to make `children = None and if not children: children = []`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham He definitely should do that, but I don't think you should use `if not children:`, in case you later want to initialize it as an empty list or something else that tests as `False`. Safer, more clear, and not much longer to use `if children is None:`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I don't quite understand why my class definition is not good and what you suggest me to do. can you modify my class definition in your post as well?

Comment: The blog post [Gotcha - Mutable default arguments](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/) explains why assigning an empty list as a default argument is likely to be an error.

Comment: @Tim, I added a quick example

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for the canonical SO question about mutable-objects-as-default-arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Using a list comprehension:

```
nodes = [node() for _ in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
nodes = [node() for _ in range(100)]
```

Python doesn't have a concept of "arrays" per se, but it has lists which are a higher-level structure. Lists can be indexed just like C arrays, and [support many more complex operations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 3):

```
[node() for _ in range(100)]
```

And as I said in my comment:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, children=None):
        if children is None: children = []
        self.children = children
```

If you used `def __init__(self, children= []):`, any changes you make to the list will change for all instances:

```
In [18]: class node(object):
   ....:     def __init__(self, children = []):
   ....:            self.children = children
   ....:         

In [19]: n1= node()

In [20]: n2 = node()

In [21]: n1.children.append("foo") # add using n1 

In [22]: n1.children
Out[22]: ['foo']

In [23]: n2.children # also effects n2's children list
Out[23]: ['foo']
```

Correct way:

```
In [24]: class node(object):
   ....:     def __init__(self, children=None):
   ....:            if children is None: children = []
   ....:            self.children = children
   ....:         

In [25]: n1= node()

In [26]: n2 = node()

In [27]: n1.children.append("foo")

In [28]: n1.children
Out[28]: ['foo']

In [29]: n2.children
Out[29]: []
```

Comment: why if using "def __init__(self, children= []):, any changes you make to the list will change for all instances"?

Comment: `map(node, range(100))` will construct `node(0)`, `node(1)`, etc., which will lead to problems when you try to use the `children` attributes of those nodes as lists.

Comment: @Tim:  Default arguments are evaluated at the time the function is created -- not when the function is called.  Another way of saying this is that `def` is an executable statement.

Comment: @Tim, yes the list is created once, so if you have a mutable default argument then you will have one object created when the function is created.